# QDesktopServices::openUrl() fails with generated path

Tags: qt

I have a problem to open a file using the QDesktopServices::openUrl() function.

I have a code that generates the absolute address of a file but when I try to run it I´m getting shellExecute error 2.

This is code I´m using:

```
void openFileMainWindow::runSong() {
QAction *act = qobject_cast<QAction *>(sender());

QString addr = "file:///";
addr.append(QString(act->data().toString()));

QByteArray tempArray  = addr.toUtf8();
const char * addrW    = tempArray.data();

QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Info"), tr("You are trying to open file:\n%1").arg(addrW), QMessageBox::Ok);

QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(addrW, QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

}

When I tried to write path manualy as "file:///.../file.mp3" it was working good, but why the generated address is not?
I also tried it with QString addr only, but with the same result.

Comment: Btw... Qt. Not QT. Qt is a cross-platform application development framework, but QT (QuickTime) - is an extensible multimedia framework developed by Apple Inc.

Comment: OK... Sorry for disturbing title. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For sure an encoding problem. QUrl takes a QString as first parameter. No idea what remained from your initial QString addr after you squeezed it into a QByteArray and then take a const char * address and finally let QUrl convert it back into a QString.

Any particular reason why you don't just pass your addr to QUrl? Without tempArray? addrW?

Comment: I tried to pass QString addr, but it didnt work. So I tried to convert it to char *

Comment: Can you say why it didn't work? Compile error? Link error? Runtime error? QUrl takes a QString. I don't see any way how using addr instead of *addrW could fail.

Comment: I finally found the mistake I did much earlier. It was just stupid mistake at where I was reading the .txt file with the addresses and so I read also the '\n' character. I fixed it by using QTextStream::readline().

But thank you for the answer anyway. I´m just beginner so sometimes I miss even such things.

Answer (score 0):

QUrl has a [`fromLocalFile()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromLocalFile) function:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(act->data().toString()));
```